# Remover trecho do HTML entre comentários específicos

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-replace

Tenho uma classe chamada `Page(page.class.php)` que "monta" a página, e uma das funções dessa classe é censurar determinado conteúdo por nível de usuário.

```php
    <?php
    class Page(){
        //(...)
        static function sensurar($str){
            $tipoInt = User::tipoInt();
            for ($i=0; $i < 11; $i++) {
                if ($tipoInt == $i) continue;
                $str = Page::clearTag2($str,"<!--a$i-->","<!--$i-->","<!--a-->");
            }
            return $str;
        }
        static function clearTag2($str,$tA,$tB,$msg=""){
            $str0 = $str;
            $pattern = "/({$tA})(.|\n)*({$tB})/";
            $str = preg_replace($pattern,$msg,$str);
            if (is_null($str)) {echo "erro"; return $str0; };
            if($str == "") {
                    $len = strlen($str0);
                    $error = preg_last_error();
                    Page::error("
                    Limpou a string.
                    [tA] = '$tA', [tB] = '$tB',[pattern] = '$pattern', [str].length = {$len}
                    $error
                    $str0
                    ","Page::clearTag2");
                }
            return $str;
        }
```

E estava funcionando maravilhosamente bem, até que começou a apresentar erro. quando utilizo na página `pagina("string")` abaixo.

```html
<pre><h2>Erro Page::clearTag2</h2>
Limpou a string.
[tA] = '<!--a5-->', [tB] = '<!--5-->',[pattern] = '/(<!--a5-->)(.|
)*(<!--5-->)/', [str].length = 6086
6
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Sistema H |Produto, Odin</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tema.d/oficial.d/css/page.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tema.d/oficial.d/css/menu.css">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            server = "http://localhost/g2%20soft/ecomerce/";
        </script>
        <script src="tema.d/oficial.d/js/wrequest.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body lang="pt-br">
        <nav id="menunav">
            <header>
    <img src="tema.d/oficial.d/img/logo com fundo transparente.png" alt="">
</header>
<ul class="menu">
      <li
  class="menufechado"
  link="perfil"
  submenu="true"
  >
  <span onclick="menuOpen(this)">+ FabricaA[Fabrica]</span>
  <ul class="submenu">
      <li
  class="menufechado"
  link="edit_perfil"
  submenu="false"
  >
  <span onclick="menuOpen(this)">Perfil</span>

</li>
<li
  class="menufechado"
  link="edit_perfil?a=sair"
  submenu="false"
  >
  <span onclick="menuOpen(this)">Sair</span>

</li>

</ul>

</li>
<li
  class="menufechado"
  link="list_meusprodutos"
  submenu="true"
  >
  <span onclick="menuOpen(this)">+ Produtos</span>
  <ul class="submenu">
      <li
  class="menufechado"
  link="list_meusprodutos"
  submenu="false"
  >
  <span onclick="menuOpen(this)">Meus Produtos</span>

</li>
<li
  class="menufechado"
  link="add_produto"
  submenu="false"
  >
  <span onclick="menuOpen(this)">Cadastrar Produto</span>

</li>
<li
  class="menufechado"
  link="list_valortipo"
  submenu="false"
  >
  <span onclick="menuOpen(this)">Tabelas de Preço</span>

</li>

</ul>

</li>
<li
  class="menufechado"
  link="list_meusclientes"
  submenu="true"
  >
  <span onclick="menuOpen(this)">+ Clientes</span>
  <ul class="submenu">
      <li
  class="menufechado"
  link="list_meusclientes"
  submenu="false"
  >
  <span onclick="menuOpen(this)">Meus Clientes</span>

</li>
<li
  class="menufechado"
  link="list_naoclientes"
  submenu="false"
  >
  <span onclick="menuOpen(this)">Não Clientes</span>

</li>

</ul>

</li>
<li
  class="menufechado"
  link="#"
  submenu="true"
  >
  <span onclick="menuOpen(this)">+ Cadastro</span>
  <ul class="submenu">
      <li
  class="menufechado"
  link="add_produto"
  submenu="false"
  >
  <span onclick="menuOpen(this)">Produto</span>

</li>
<li
  class="menufechado"
  link="add_formadepagamento"
  submenu="false"
  >
  <span onclick="menuOpen(this)">Forma de pagamento</span>

</li>
<li
  class="menufechado"
  link="add_prasodeentrega"
  submenu="false"
  >
  <span onclick="menuOpen(this)">Praso de pagamento</span>

</li>

</ul>

</li>
<li
  class="menufechado"
  link="list_pedidosfabrica"
  submenu="false"
  >
  <span onclick="menuOpen(this)">Pedidos</span>

</li>
<li
  class="menufechado"
  link="mensagens"
  submenu="false"
  >
  <span onclick="menuOpen(this)">Mensagens</span>

</li>
<li
  class="menufechado"
  link=""
  submenu="true"
  >
  <span onclick="menuOpen(this)">+ Relatorios</span>
  <ul class="submenu">
      <li
  class="menufechado"
  link="rela_produtosvendidos"
  submenu="false"
  >
  <span onclick="menuOpen(this)">Produtos Vendidos</span>

</li>
<li
  class="menufechado"
  link="rela_produtoscadastrados"
  submenu="false"
  >
  <span onclick="menuOpen(this)">Produtos Cadastrados</span>

</li>
<li
  class="menufechado"
  link="rela_clientescadastrados"
  submenu="false"
  >
  <span onclick="menuOpen(this)">Clientes Cadastrados</span>

</li>

</ul>

</li>
<li
  class="menufechado"
  link=""
  submenu="false"
  >
  <span onclick="menuOpen(this)">Lançamentos</span>

</li>

</ul>

        </nav>
        <content>
            <h1>Produto, Odin</h1>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="tema.d/oficial.d/css/view_produto.css">
<div class="page_listabas">
  <!--a5-->
  <div class="page_abalabel " onclick="link('list_loja')">Loja</div>
  <!--5-->
  <div class="page_abalabel page_abalabel_opened">Ver</div>
  <!--a6-->
  <div class="page_abalabel" onclick="link('edit_produto?id=52')">Detalhes</div>
  <div class="page_abalabel" onclick="link('edit_produtomidia?id=52')">Midias</div>
  <!--6-->
</div>
<div class="page_aba">
  <div id="referencia">Odin</div>
  <div class="midias">
    <div class="midia_view">
      <img src="anexo\97" alt="midia0" id="midia_view_img">
    </div>
    <div class="midias_left">
      <span> <img src="tema.d/oficial.d/img/midiasview_arrow_left.svg" alt=""> </span>
    </div>
    <div class="midias_right">
      <span> <img src="tema.d/oficial.d/img/midiasview_arrow_right.svg" alt=""> </span>
    </div>
    <div class="midia_list"><div class="">
  <img src="anexo/97" alt="" onclick="setMidia(this)">
</div>
<div class="">
  <img src="anexo/98" alt="" onclick="setMidia(this)">
</div>
</div>
  </div>
  <div class="detalhes">
    <p>Odim, tambem conhecido como pai de todos.</p>
    <p>
      2cx por <valor>R$ 0,00</valor>
    </p>
    <p>[52]Hidralica Industrial/Eletrica</p>
  </div>
  <div class="formasdepagamento">
    <p>Podendo ser pago:</p>
    {{formas de pagamento}}
  </div>
  <div class="outrosprodutos">
    <div class="produto">
      <img src="anexo/0" alt="">
    </div>
    {{outrosprodutos}}
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="tema.d/oficial.d/js/view_produto.js"></script>

            <footer>G2</footer>
        </content>
        <div class="menu-button" onclick="menuShow()">&equiv;</div>
        <div class="flutuante" id="flutuante">Loading...</div>
        <div class="msgbox_fundo" id="msgbox_fundo" onclick="MSGbox.close()">
            <div class="msgbox_box">
                <span class="button msgbox_close" onclick="MSGbox.close()">X</span>

                <div class="msgbox_conteudo" id="msgbox_conteudo">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="tema.d/oficial.d/js/page.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="tema.d/oficial.d/js/menu.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

Andei fazendo alguns testes, acho que a possível causa do problema seja a expressão.

```
$pattern = "/({$tA})(.|\n)*({$tB})/";
```

Eu chutaria que há um limite de caracteres que uma expressão pode verificar.

Comment: Qual é a mesagem, completa, de erro?

Comment: Não existe mensagem de erro (não nativo), o que acontece é que a função preg_replace() retorna "null" no lugar da string "tratada". mas não vejo motivo para isso

Comment: A [documentação](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php#refsect1-function.preg-replace-returnvalues) diz que se o retorno é NULL então ocorreu algum erro. Vc pode ver o retorno de `preg_last_error()` para saber qual foi o erro: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-last-error.php

Comment: O erro esta "quase tratado" no código postado, retorna erro 6 (PREG_BAD_UTF8_OFFSET_ERROR), o problema é: Porque? Como solucionar? ou ate, se existe uma outra maneira de fazer?

Comment: No [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/pcre.constants.php) está escrito >`PREG_BAD_UTF8_OFFSET_ERROR`  Retornado pela `preg_last_error()` se o offset não correspondeu ao início de um válido code point UTF-8 (somente quando executando uma regex em modo UTF-8).

Comment: Não entendi, vc passa todo o HTML como uma string para a função `sensurar`? Qual deveria ser o resultado?

Comment: O arquivo é UTF-8 e deve ter sido gravado com BOM. Se for o caso deve se remover o BOM antes de ser processado pelo `preg_replace()`

Comment: Verifiquei, converti, reescrevi arquivos(template). E mesmo assim continuou o mesmo erro.

Comment: @AugustoVasques Na verdade o erro 6 é `PREG_JIT_STACKLIMIT_ERROR` (não poderia ser erro de UTF-8 porque a regex só roda neste modo se tiver a flag `u`, e nesse caso não tem). Talvez seja algo relativo a alguma config no php.ini,  pois fiz uns testes e não deu o mesmo erro. Vou pesquisar um pouco mais e se for o caso, coloco uma resposta

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No seu código, o retorno de [`preg_last_error()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-last-error.php) foi `6`, que corresponde ao erro  [`PREG_JIT_STACKLIMIT_ERROR`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pcre.constants.php#constant.preg-jit-stacklimit-error). Basicamente, este erro refere-se ao [PCRE JIT](http://www.pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcrejit.html), que é um recurso que faz várias otimizações em uma regex. Mas estas otimizações não são de graça: elas precisam de memória extra para suas estruturas internas, e este erro ocorre quando a regex acaba usando mais memória que a disponível (por *default*, [o JIT usa um *stack* de 32K de memória](http://www.pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcrejit.html#SEC8)).

O PCRE JIT [vem habilitado por padrão no PHP >= 7](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pcre.configuration.php#ini.pcre.jit), e pesquisando encontrei vários links que sugerem [desabilitá-lo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34850443) no `php.ini` (setando `pcre.jit = 0`) ou diretamente no código, chamando `ini_set('pcre.jit', false)`. Mas creio que a melhor opção seja otimizar a regex para que ela seja mais eficiente, consumindo assim menos recursos e evitando que o *stack* do JIT estoure.

Para começar, sua regex faz uso de parênteses, o que cria [grupos de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), que consomem memória extra, já que é uma estrutura a mais a ser gerada e mantida (isso também consome mais memória ao procurar pelos *matches*, pois os grupos tem que ser guardados separadamente). Mas como você não está usando os grupos (e simplesmente substituindo tudo por outra string), pode removê-los.

Outro ponto é a [alternância](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) `(.|\n)`. O ponto é ["qualquer caractere, exceto quebras de linha"](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html), e talvez por isso você tenha colocado o `|\n` depois. O problema é que isso também é ineficiente, pois para cada caractere é feito o teste (se corresponde a um ou outro).

Felizmente, em várias linguagens e engines, existe uma opção que faz com que o ponto corresponda também a quebras de linhas, e a diferença é brutal. Veja [aqui a regex com alternância](https://regex101.com/r/T73TOv/1/), e repare na quantidade de passos executados (mais de 11 mil). Já usando a *flag* `s` (que faz com que o ponto corresponda a quebras de linha), a [regex fica mais eficiente](https://regex101.com/r/T73TOv/2/) e precisa de pouco mais que 2600 passos (cerca de 4 vezes menos passos).

Você ainda pode melhorar um pouco mais. Por padrão, os quantificadores - como o `*` - [são gananciosos](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#greedytrap) e tentam pegar o máximo possível de caracteres. Como estamos usando o ponto, que pega qualquer caractere, ele tenta ir até o final da string, e depois vai voltando até encontrar algo que satisfaça o restante da regex (processo conhecido como *backtracking*, que também consome mais recursos, já que a *engine* precisa manter os estados em memória até que todas as possibilidades se esgotem).

Para evitar isso, você pode usar `.*?`, que torna o quantificador [preguiçoso](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#lazy_solution). Assim, ele pega o mínimo possível de caracteres, e vai avançando aos poucos na string (em vez de pegar tudo e ir voltando). Isso diminui drasticamente a quantidade de passos executados (veja que nesse caso, [diminui para cerca de 490 passos](https://regex101.com/r/T73TOv/3/)).

---

Resumindo, sua regex poderia ficar assim:

```
$pattern = "/{$tA}.*?{$tB}/s";
```

Retirei os parênteses, já que não estou usando os grupos para nada. Usei a [*flag* `s`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) para que o ponto corresponda também a quebras de linha, e usei o quantificador preguiçoso `*?` para diminuir o *backtracking*.

Na minha máquina eu não tive os mesmos erros que você, mas testando no IdeOne.com podemos ver que [a sua regex original de fato retorna o erro 6](https://ideone.com/5r4NNB), e alterando para a regex acima, [o erro não ocorre mais](https://ideone.com/POLxah).

Resumindo, sua suspeita quanto a quantidade de caracteres não era completamente infundada. Afinal, quanto maior a string, mais *backtracking* será necessário para a regex encontrar os *matches*. E ao melhorar a regex, podemos diminuir o *backtracking*, e consequentemente, os recursos usados para a mesma rodar.

---

#### Não use regex

Mas talvez o problema principal seja o fato de estar processando um arquivo HTML com regex - já que essa [não é a melhor ferramenta para a tarefa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454). Embora regex possa funcionar, em muitos casos é melhor usar uma API específica. No caso, você poderia usar [`DOMDocument`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php):

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHtml($html); // $html é uma string contendo todo o HTML
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
for ($i=0; $i < 11; $i++) {
    foreach ($xpath->query('//comment()') as $comment) { // procura comentários
        if ($comment->nodeValue == "a$i") { // comentário inicial
            $parent = $comment->parentNode;
            $remover = [];
            // percorrer os nós irmãos até encontrar o comentário que fecha
            $node = $comment->nextSibling;
            while (true) {
                $remover[] = $node;
                $node = $node->nextSibling;
                if ($node->nodeType == XML_COMMENT_NODE && $node->nodeValue == "$i") {
                    $remover[] = $node;
                    break;
                }
            }
            foreach($remover as $n) { // remover
                $parent->removeChild($n);
            }
            // trocar o comentário "aX" por "a"
            $parent->replaceChild($dom->createComment('a'), $comment);
        }
    }
}
// imprimir o HTML final (com as tags removidas)
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Assim, podemos percorrer o HTML procurando por comentários. E quando o comentário corresponde ao que você quer encontrar, basta percorrer os demais nós até encontrar o comentário que encerra o trecho a ser censurado, e remover todos (no final, ainda substituo o texto do comentário, da mesma forma que a regex estava fazendo).

Answer (score 1):

Estava fazendo uns testes, e percebi que o erro sempre acontecia depois de 6000 caracteres. Dividi a String e testei... bom... funcionou. Segue o código:

```
    static function clearTag($str,$tA,$tB,$msg=""){
    $pattern = "/({$tA})(.|\n)*({$tB})/";
    $str1 = "";
    $str0 = $str;
    $str = "";
    while ($str0 != "") {
        if (strlen($str0)>6000) {
            $str1 .= substr($str0,0,6000);
            $str .= preg_replace($pattern,$msg,$str1);
            //-------
            if(preg_last_error() != 0) {
                    $len = strlen($str0);
                    $error = preg_last_error();
                    Page::error("
                    Limpou a string.
                    [tA] = '$tA', [tB] = '$tB',[pattern] = '$pattern', [str].length = {$len}
                    $error
                    $str0
                                    ","Page::clearTag2");
                }
            //-------
            $str0 = substr($str0,6000);
        }else {
             $str .= preg_replace($pattern,$msg,$str0);
             //----------
             if(preg_last_error() != 0) {
                     $len = strlen($str0);
                     $error = preg_last_error();
                     Page::error("
                     Limpou a string.
                     [tA] = '$tA', [tB] = '$tB',[pattern] = '$pattern', [str].length = {$len}
                     $error
                     $str0
                                     ","Page::clearTag2");
                 }
             //------
             $str0 = "";
        }
        //------------ Erro ----------
    }
    return $str;
}
```

O problema é apenas que se a "censura" estiver na altura do caractere "6000", não vai tirar o conteúdo.